# drawing framework in java

Tags: java, java-2d, eclipse-gef

I'm looking for a java 2d drawing framework. I'm building an application in which you load an image, and you should be able to draw on top of the image. But everything which is drawn should be selectable, modifiable, have properties etc. Actually Eclipse GEF (or Graphiti) looked really good, but that seems to be focused on drawing diagrams only. I would also need support for freehand drawing, bezier curves, lines etc.

Anybody know something like Eclipse GEF but which also supports freehand drawing and bezier curves? Or maybe it does and I didn't look quite good enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly write a simple editors yourself using `JPanel` and a custom `paintComponent()` method. But creating a useful editor with undo, etc. is a lot of work.

Try [jfig](http://tams-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/jfig/index.html) which is shareware (free for 30 days, then $30). It has a framework with editor components plus a default editor which you can tweak.

Comment: The drawing is indeed no problem, I've done large scale projects on that before, but I'm looking for a framework like GEF which would give me instantly a GUI which I can customize for my application, and which would already have support for many basic functions a drawing program would need (undo being the least of it)

Comment: Try jfig, it has a framework for all the editor parts and a default implementation that you can tweak.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that crucial point (being able to extend and modify the GUI)